# No response on stdout runtime error ~ HackerRank problem

Tags: java, if-statement, runtime-error

Below is the code for my if-statement, which is supposed to print out the String "Weird" or "Not Weird" depending on the value of n.

```
public class Solution {
    public static String weirdOrNotWeird(){

    int n;
    String ans = "";

    // if n is odd or n is even & 5 < n < 21 print Weird
    if((n % 2 == 1) || ((n % 2 == 0) && (n > 5 && n < 21))){
        ans = "Weird";

    // otherwise print Not Weird
    } else {
        ans = "Not Weird";
    } 
    System.out.println(ans);
    return ans;
    }
}
```

When I compile, I get a runtime error that says "no response on stdout", and so doesn't give me an output.

```
private static final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int n = scanner.nextInt();
    scanner.skip("(\r\n|[\n\r\u2028\u2029\u0085])?");

    scanner.close();
}
```

This is the rest of the code from the problem, but I don't have any errors in this part.

UPDATE: I didn't define int n as a parameter in my `weirdOrNotWeird()` function, and I didn't call my `weirdOrNotWeird()` function in my main method.  After I did those things my code worked.

Comment: remove System.out.println from your code before submitting code.

Comment: where are you calling `weirdOrNotWeird` function?

Comment: I removed System.out.println from if-statement as per above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define your method with one parameter and pass `n` as parameter in this method.

```
 public static String weirdOrNotWeird(int n) {
        String ans = "";
        // if n is odd or n is even & 5 < n < 21 print Weird
        if ((n % 2 == 1) || ((n % 2 == 0) && (n > 5 && n < 21))) {
            ans = "Weird";
            // otherwise print Not Weird
        } else {
            ans = "Not Weird";
        }
        return ans;
    }
```

And call you method after `scanner.skip("(\r\n|[\n\r\u2028\u2029\u0085])?");` passing `n` as parameter like following:

```
int n = scanner.nextInt();
scanner.skip("(\r\n|[\n\r\u2028\u2029\u0085])?");
System.out.println(weirdOrNotWeird(n));
scanner.close();
```